# Errors while I am trying to create replication to my postgres database

Tags: postgresql, replication, recovery

I am trying to create "replication" for my database. I watched many tutorials and documentations.
Finally, I followed this tutorial in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaPnYQBBdyU&t=1034s).

The problem is when I add the recovery data in recovery.conf I surprised that the whole cluster does work and its failed to start with :
`sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-test` Where "test" is the backup cluster.
Then I tried many solutions but it was zero result. Next I removed data in the "test" cluster and I redo the steps for `pg_basebackup` without adding any thing to recovery.conf file and its started correctly and synchronized with the existing data in main cluster at the backup moment.
Note : Its not synchronized with any data have been inserted recently after `pg_basebackup`.
So, The problem is : Why when Adding data to recovery.conf file its failed to start and **Absolutely** I need to add data to make the replication works fine?
Or If you can provide me with a suitable tutorial or documentation to this replication.

Note 2 : I am trying to replication on the same PC then I'll move to it on cloud or on another PC.

Here is datasheet I followed with the video :
[Sheet](https://www.scalingpostgres.com/tutorials/postgresql-streaming-replication/)

Comment: This is a wall of confused text that does not tell us at all what you did. A list of the exact commands you ran would be more helpful. Why do people watch random videos rather than reading the official documentation?

Comment: If you inspected my "Note 2" well, you'll now what commands I used.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered it. The file recovery.conf that is no longer used in postgresql 12.

I have followed other documents and solved my problem.

Now I have two synchronized devices.